# Display a list in a 10x10 table

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print out the elements of a list of 100 items in a 10x10 table. I have this:

```
    for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
        System.out.print(array[b] + " ");
        if ((b > 0) && (b % 10) == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }// end if
    }// end for
```

Which works....almost. It displays 11 elements on the first line, and 9 on the final But all of the other rows are fine, just not the first one. I have no idea why and I don't know how to fix this.. please help!

**EDIT:**

This is an example of the output I get, notice there are 11 items on the first row, and 9 onn the final. There should be 10 on each:

```
0 1 2 4 5 5 7 8 8 9 11 
11 13 15 16 17 17 18 23 24 25 
25 28 30 31 31 31 33 33 33 35 
36 36 38 38 40 40 40 40 42 43 
44 44 44 45 47 48 49 49 52 52 
53 53 55 55 55 55 55 57 58 58 
58 59 60 60 62 63 64 64 64 64 
64 66 66 67 67 68 70 70 70 72 
73 74 75 75 76 77 77 78 82 84 
86 89 91 91 92 93 93 96 97
```

Comment: @avgvstvs its an array with 100 random numbers from 0-100

Comment: This is working fine, what error you are getting

Comment: It's not giving an error, @BhavikAmbani , it works just fine, however it displays 11 elements in the very first rown, and it needs only 10. It should be a 10x10 table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inner condition should be:

```
if (((b + 1) % 10) == 0) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

Example: let's say `b` is `9`. So you've printed `0` through `9` (ten items). Then you reach this line. You see that (((9 + 1) % 10 == 0) so it will print a new line after it's done printing the 9th item. Then you reach `b = 19` and you see that it will print a new line after it prints `19`. Etc.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! thank you so much!! I knew there was something to do with starting a position over but everything I tried failed... thanks!!